Does https server is required for captive portal implementation in ios devices
I have implemented captive portal in psoc 6 microcontroller using lwip stack in c language. I have used http server. The captive portal is working correctly with android devices and windows devices. It is not working with ios devices.I have included url's used by apple to check connectivity. But still It is not working. Is it because Iam using http server? Please let me know if anyone can help me.
I read somewhere, ios devices uses https request to check captive portal, but Iam using http. If that is the issue, Please let me know if any alternative is there.

Consider trying caddy in front of the portal to enable HTTPS in your testing environment, or get a free cert through let's encrypt to see if SSL is a hard requirement for iOS
